# Maven pom.xml issue: Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata

Tags: java, spring, maven

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:maven-plugin:3.5.1:runtime Cause: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)  pom.xml
```

When pull project from Bitbucket I get this error?

Comment: Can you please add the pom of the project your are trying to build to your question?

Comment: Is the pom.xml both well-formed and valid?